# Why it is not updating the YourMail__c after Recursion Handling?

Tags: apex, trigger, recursion

Class:

```
public class Hr {
  public static Boolean f_t = true;
}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger HandleTrigger on Input__c (before insert) {
if(Trigger.isInsert){
        if(Hr.f_t){

    Input__c acc = new Input__c(YourMail__c='tringtriggers@gmail.com');
      Hr.f_t=false; 
            //acc.YourMail__c='tringtriggers@gmail.com';           
            insert acc;
}
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your trigger is creating a *second* record rather than updating the first record. You'd want to change your code as follows:

```
trigger HandleTrigger on Input__c (before insert) {
    for(Input__c record: Trigger.new) {
        record.YourEmail__c = 'tringtrigger@gmail.com';
    }
}
```

Recursion blocking is not necessary in this case.